# Это сложное предложение или простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми?

Tags: синтаксис

*Мы должны содействовать открытому и инновационному росту, содействовать равномерному восстановлению мировой экономики, поддерживать многостороннюю систему торговли, основой которой является Всемирная торговая организация, внедрять новейшие научно-технические достижения в пользу всех стран, а также продвигать экономическую глобализацию в русле открытого, инклюзивного, сбалансированного и взаимовыгодного развития.*

Правильно ли мое предположение? Мы – подлежащее, а однородные сказуемые:  1) должны содействовать, 2) содействовать. 3) поддерживать 4)внедрять 5) продвигать?

Смущает, что с остальными глаголами не употребляется "должны".

И чем является часть предложения "основой которой является Всемирная торговая организация"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

*Мы **должны содействовать** открытому и инновационному росту, **содействовать** равномерному восстановлению мировой экономики, **поддерживать** многостороннюю систему торговли, основой которой является Всемирная торговая организация, **внедрять** новейшие научно-технические достижения в пользу всех стран, **а также продвигать** экономическую глобализацию в русле открытого, инклюзивного, сбалансированного и взаимовыгодного развития.*

1. Это простое предложение, **осложненное однородными сказуемыми**. Сказуемое составное глагольное (модальная связка "должны" + инфинитив). При этом однородными отношениями связаны инфинитивы, а глагольная связка "должны" не повторяется.

Связь бессоюзная и союзная (используется замыкающий союз А ТАКЖЕ), запятая перед ним ставится.

2. К одному из однородных членов относится обособленное **придаточное определительное предложение**: *..поддерживать многостороннюю систему **торговли*** (какой?), *основой которой является Всемирная торговая организация...*
3. Предложение неудобно для прочтения, также желательно исключить повторы слов. Вариант редактирования:

Мы **должны способствовать** открытому инновационному росту **и внедрять** новейшие научно-технические достижения в пользу всех стран; **должны содействовать** равномерному восстановлению мировой экономики, **поддерживать** многостороннюю систему торговли, основой которой является Всемирная торговая организация, **а также продвигать** экономическую глобализацию в русле открытого, инклюзивного, сбалансированного и взаимовыгодного развития

Comment: Смысл правки мне неясен.  Придаточное определительное построено корректно. Союзное слово КОТОРОЙ находится в середине придаточного предложения; в придаточном играет роль дополнения. В исправленном виде текст разделен на два простых предложения: мы должны; (мы) должны.